# Autofilter with VBA in more sheets

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, helper

i want to filter in more than one sheet for one specific item e.g, "Harry"

My macro does not say that i am wrong, but nothing happens..

```
Sub New_Marko_for_selection()

Worksheets("Sheet53").Range("A1:D4").AutoFilter,Criteria1:="Harry"

end sub
```

Best Regards

Comment: You need loop here. Loop should iterate through required sheet.

Comment: Odd, you've verified "Harry" exists in this range and nothing happens?  What happens when you do this, `Worksheets("Sheet53").Range("A1:D4").AutoFilter,Criteria1:="Harry*"` ?

Comment: If i do this, the filter is not popping up so nothing happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is typical code to apply AutoFilter to several sheets:

```
Sub New_Marko_for_selection()
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3"))
        sh.Range("$A$1:$D$4").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Harry"
    Next sh
End Sub
```

**Note:**

- I specified the column
- I list the required sheets in the `Array()`